# ¿Cómo conectarse a una base de datos en un servidor remoto?

Tags: php, sql

estoy haciendo un tutorial para poder subir fotos desde un formulario. Este debe estar enlazado a una base de datos que tengo en un servidor web (bluehost). Revisando varios tutoriales me muestra que debo usar localhost en el archivo php de conexión; como se muestra acá:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","USUARIO","CONSTRASEÑA");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxx");
?>
```

Subiendo el archivo al servidor no me funciona. ¿Debo poner la IP de la base de datos en vez del localhost?

Porque los tutoriales que he visto lo hacen de forma local y necesito trabajarlo remotamente

GRACIAS

Comment: GRACIAS .... Si ya hable con ellos y me dieron la IP, pero vuelvo a subir el archivo php y no conecta ... Este es el turorial que estoy siguiento. ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E57R8gFnNlU

Comment: Si el archivo PHP está subido en Bluehost tienes que poner `localhost`, si el archivo está en tu ordenador, tienes que autorizar la IP de tu ordenador en tu base de datos (Bluehost) para poder conectar, si no tienes una IP fija en tu casa tendrás que usar llaves públicas/privadas. Esto es por seguridad, para que no cualquiera desde cualquier sitio pueda conectar a la base de datos. La cuestión clave es ¿dónde está el archivo con el que te quieres conectar?

Comment: Y ten en cuenta que la función `mysql_` es obsoleta. Si tienes PHP 7 ese código no funcionará, tienes que pasar a `mysqli`  o a PDO.

Comment: Estoy probando con este codigo: <?php
$servername = "dominio.com";
$database = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXX";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>  ... y me sale este error: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'Servi20'@'box5643.bluehost.com' (using password: YES)

Comment: No nos has dicho si estás en un archivo subido a Bluehost. si es así, en vez de `box5643.bluehost.com` tienes que poner  `localhost` y verificar que el nombre de usuario y la constraseña son correctas. Y observa que estás pasando como primer parámetro `$servername`, que tiene el valor de `"dominio.com"`, ahí precisamente tiene que ir `localhost`, no `dominio.com`. Prueba así: **`mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database);`**

Comment: EXCELENTE!!!!! ... Funciono ... MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 3):

Los parámetros que tienes que pasar a [`mysqli_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) son los siguientes y en ese mismo orden, sin cambiarlos:

1. Nombre del host
2. Nombre del usuario
3. Contraseña
4. Nombre de la base de datos

En Bluehost, como en casi todos los proveedores de hosting, el host es `localhost`, en algunos casos en vez de esto hay que poner la IP `127.0.0.1`

En tu código estás pasando `dominio.com` como nombre de host.

Intenta este código:

```
$host="localhost";
/*ATENCÍON: Asegúrate de poner las credenciales correctas*/
$database = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$username = "XXXXX"; 
$password = "XXXXXX"; 
// Create connection 
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database); 
// Check connection 
if (!$conn) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
} 
echo "Connected successfully"; 
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Puedes usar también el [estilo orientado a objetos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php), es más claro y más moderno y recomendado por PHP (los comentarios en el código son del Manual de PHP).

```
$host="localhost";
/*ATENCÍON: Asegúrate de poner las credenciales correctas*/
$database = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$username = "XXXXX"; 
$password = "XXXXXX"; 

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

/*
 * Esta es la forma OO "oficial" de hacerlo,
 * AUNQUE $connect_error estaba averiado hasta PHP 5.2.9 y 5.3.0.
 */
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error de Conexión Nº: {$conn->connect_errno} {$mysqli->connect_error}");
}

/*Te recomiendo vivamente que pongas siempre un charset adecuado a la conexion*/
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
echo "Connected successfully"; 
$conn->close();
```